# the onclick function for a button not working in a php variable

Tags: php, html, materialize

I am trying to store html+materialize css code in a php variable and and print it on the screen. I also have a button with a onclick function in it. But the onclick function is not working. Its not calling the php function which it is supposed to call when the user clicks the button.

```
$s='<div class="container">
            <div class="card hoverable">
                <div class="card-content activator waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                <table>
                    <tr><td><h1 class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4" id="content"> Cnumber:</h1></td><td><h1 class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">'.$brow["id"].'</h1></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><p class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">river:</p></td><td><p class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">'.$brow["river"].'</p></td></tr>
                   <tr><td> <p class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Type:</p></td><td><p class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">'.$brow["type"].'</p></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><p class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">People:</p></td><td><p class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">'.$people_count.'</p></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">People<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">'.$people_list.'</p>
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" onclick="set_session()" id='.$brow["cab_id"].'>Share</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>';
            echo $s;
```

Comment: You can't call a PHP function from `onclick`. PHP runs on the server, `onclick` runs Javascript on the client.

Comment: You need to use AJAX to invoke a PHP script in response to clicks.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" onclick="set_session()" id='.$brow["cab_id"].'>Share</button>
```

set_session() is handled like a js function here.